# How should I address this professor in the US?

Tags: american-english, politeness, conversation

Realted to this question [How should I address a professor in the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42931/how-should-i-address-a-professor-in-the-us)
I have a question how to adress the professor in the US in my concrete situation. In the last E-Mails I wrote "Dear professor ..." and "Kind regards, Aleksana last name", and he had always responded with "Dear Aleksana",..."Best regards, Marius."

What to do now? Shall I address him by his first name now? I.e. shall I respond with "Dear Marius,"...."Kind regards, Aleksana"? Or shall I continue adressing the professor by his last name?

Regards

Comment: I would stick with *Professor Lastname* until you are sure you have established a more intimate relationship with him, or he asks you to address him by his first name.  I was on first name terms with many professors as a grad student, but the same was by no means the case when I was an undergrad!

Comment: I'd suggest you direct this question to the [Academia Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) site.  They'll be more in tune with current customs at US universities,

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon for people to sign an email with their first name as hint that it's okay for you to start using their first name.

There's no way to know the best way to address a professor unless you ask that professor. Some professors prefer formal titles; some would rather students use their first name.

A "safe" way to handle this is to address your professor as *Professor* in your next email. Then, at the end of the email, say something like this:

> *P.S. I noticed that you've been signing your emails with your first name (Marius). Would you prefer that I address you as "Marius" in my replies? Or do you mind if I keep calling you "Professor" instead?*